# Django how to distinguish whether the password is wrong or the "user.is_active" is false?

Tags: python, django, web

I use `user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)`,but I can't distinguish whether the password is wrong or the `user.is_active` is false,because both of them the `user` is None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the user with the given username and check if it is inactive:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user = get_user_model().objects.filter(username=username).first()
if user is None:
    # user did not exists
    pass
elif not user.is_active:
    # user is not active
    pass
else:
    # password was incorrect
    pass
```

Comment: But in this way, I can know whether someone's account is available without a password. I want to avoid this problem.

Comment: @PeaceSheep: exactly what problem? You can specify that in a view where the user has to pass a password, and if it returns `None`, you an check if the user for the given `username` exists, is available, etc. You do not have to login that user.